# Merging changes causes extra checkin

Tags: git

When I commit and push my changes, it causes another checkin which merges prior commits from somebody else.  For example, I change one file, `Readme.txt`, and commit it, then do a git pull. Some changes are added to my repository.  Then I push my changes.  There is an extra checkin that says:

```
Merge branch 'mainline' of https://example.com into mainline
```

How do I avoid this, and only check in my change?  It seems like this is a duplicate checkin, which somebody else checked in.

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is called a *merge-commit*.

[This](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) is a very good page to read:

> Instead of just moving the branch pointer forward, Git creates a new
>   snapshot that results from this three-way merge and automatically
>   creates a new commit that points to it. This is referred to as a
>   **merge commit**, and is special in that it has more than one parent.

A *merge-commit* is a commit that bring together two lines of work, meaning it has two parent commits, one for your current work, and one for the other side of the merge.

To avoid these commits you can use tools like *rebase* to re-play your commits on top of the code you are merging in. This is a complicated topic, so I would recommend following a few [rebase tutorials](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing/) to get your bearings first, as well as some potential pitfalls.

[Here](http://kernowsoul.com/blog/2012/06/20/4-ways-to-avoid-merge-commits-in-git/) is an article about avoiding merge-commits.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is a normal, common occurrence when you're cooperating with others through a central repository, and should not be regarded as a problem. It is git's way of dealing with the fact that someone has pushed a commit before you had a chance to push your commit. It's merely an accident of timing.

Comment: I understand that, but there should be a way to avoid this.  Especially if both checkins are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no conflicts between what you have done and what you are pulling down, the usual solution to this is to use a pull rebase:

```
git pull --rebase
```

What this will do is:

- Fetch updates from the remote
- Rewind your commits
- Apply the incoming commits to your tree
- And finally, replay your local (un-pushed) commits *after* the incoming ones

The end result is as if you had done a `git pull`, magically made all of your changes instantaneously, and then committed them.

If there is a conflict between your local commits and the incoming ones, you will still have to do the usual merge conflict resolution. But if there are not, this will generally result in a cleaner history and fewer merge commits.

Let's say you start from commit `A` and make your local commit `B`:

```
A --- B
```

Meanwhile, another developer starting from `A` adds `C`, `D`, and `E`:

```
A --- C --- D --- E
```

When you pull, what happens is the two divergent branches are merged. You end up with a final state, `F`:

```
A --- C --- D --- E --- F
 \--- B ---------------/
```

If you use `git pull --rebase`, it would get the remote commits, and then append your local commits *after* them. So you would end up with this, and no merge commit.

```
A --- C --- D --- E ---- B
```

(Again, assuming no merge conflict occurs.)

Answer (score 0):

A fast forward merge could avoid such merge commit. If the last common commit of Branch A and Branch B is the last commit of Branch A but not the last commit of Branch B, merge B to A is a fast forward merge. That is, the sequence of A's commits is **a true subset** of the sequence of B's commits. Let's see these cases. Every number is a commit.

1. A:1-2-3-4, B:1-2-3-4. set(A)=set(B). Merge A to B or B to A results in nothing.
2. A:1-2-3-4, B:1-2-3-4-5. set(A) is a true subset of set(B). Merge A to B, nothing happens. Merge B to A, a fast forward merge by default.
3. A:1-2-3-4, B:1-2-3-5. set(A)'s last commit 4 is not in set(B) and set(B)'s last commit 5 is not in set(A). Merge A to B, or B to A both lead to a non fast forward merge like in your case.

`git merge --no-ff` always makes a non fast forward merge if a merge can be made. `git merge --ff-only` always fails if it's not going to be a fast forward merge.

You could use `git rebase`, `git reset --hard` and `git cherry-pick` to make your 2 branches into what's it like in Case 2.